# Drupal google analytics counter module failing cron run hence data is not fetched

Tags: debugging, drupal, cron, drupal-modules

The plan is to use the google analytics counter module to show the view count of some belonging to a certain content type.
So i followed the documentation that is being provided (https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/google-analytics-counter)
Now after following the steps and doing the necessary configurations when i am running cron i am getting this error

```
`Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Drupal\Core\Cron->processQueue() (line 264 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php).
Drupal\Core\Cron->processQueue(Object, Object) (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Cron->processQueues() (Line: 162)
Drupal\Core\Cron->run() (Line: 75)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run() (Line: 272)
Drupal\admin_toolbar_tools\Controller\ToolbarController->runCron()`
```

So i checked out the code and what i figured out is when the cron is run, and the worker is google analytics counter the pluginid,plugindefintion, and the configuration is not getting passed and hence $lease_time = $worker->getPluginDefinition()['cron']['time']; this is receiving null value, and the cron run is stopped abruptly and it's throwing error/warning mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in issue [#3387501](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter/issues/3387501).
Please update to the latest release ([4.0.3](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter/releases/4.0.3) as of today).